# Rails validation of an attribute being an instance of a particular class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Is there a way to do this without using custom validators?

Comment: I don't think there is a built in validation for this. Why do you not want to use custom validations?

Comment: It's not that I dont want to use them, but I thought it was a common enough situation to warrant a built in validation, so I wanted to make sure about it. BTW, post this as an answer and I will accept it, in case anyone else is wondering this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP's request, here is the short comment exchange under the original question:

I don't think there is a built in validation for this. Why do you not want to use custom validations? – MrDanA Feb 15 at 17:05

It's not that I dont want to use them, but I thought it was a common enough situation to warrant a built in validation, so I wanted to make sure about it. BTW, post this as an answer and I will accept it, in case anyone else is wondering this – agente_secreto 20 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I do understand this right, but I think the method .class will bring it.

As everything in Ruby is a object, it's easy to use.

For example:

```
"Test".class 
=> String
```

Comment: similarly: "Test".is_a?(String)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old question, but I needed to do something like this and figured out I would share my solution, in case someone else needed to do something like this in future.

What I needed was to test if specified attribute was DateTime or Time. This was on custom class (not ActiveRecord).

I ended up with this:

```rb
class MyClass

    attr_accessor :value
    attr_reader :value_class

    include ActiveModel::Validations
    validates_inclusion_of :value_class, in: [DateTime, Time]

    def value_class
      @value.class
    end

end
```

Hope this helps anyone.